# How to read a div details with / without scrapping web page which is not present in source code in java?

Tags: selenium, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing, microsoft-edge-extension

I have a use case where I want to read the version of the published extension on edge store.
The link of any published extension is as follows -> https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/incognito-adblocker/efpgcmfgkpmogadebodiegjleafcmdcb

Now Here the problem I am facing is that the span where the version is location. ( Span ID is "versionLabel" ), has a parent div called "root". Now if we inspect it and check we can see all the children divs of this "root" div. But if we see the source of this page ( Ctrl + U ). This div always shows up empty with no details.

```
    <div id="root" style="min-height: 100vh"></div>
```

I am using Jsoup to parse this page and get this details but because this div "root" is empty. I can not able to read this "verisonLabel" details. Is there any way to do this ?

Please refer the ways I have already tried but none worked.

1.

```
String URL = "https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/incognito-adblocker/efpgcmfgkpmogadebodiegjleafcmdcb";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Element version = doc.getElementById("versionLabel");
```

2. 

```
Document demo = Jsoup.parse(URL);
Element newHere = demo.getElementById("versionLabel");
```

3. 

```
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(URL);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Get started free']"));
        System.out.println(e);
```

4. 

```
String webpage = "https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/incognito-adblocker/efpgcmfgkpmogadebodiegjleafcmdcb";
URL url = new URL(webpage);
        BufferedReader readr = 
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        // Enter filename in which you want to download
        BufferedWriter writer = 
          new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Download.html"));
          
        // read each line from stream till end
        String line;
        while ((line = readr.readLine()) != null) {
            writer.write(line);
        }

        readr.close();
        writer.close();
```

In each of this ways, because the "root" div itself is empty, I am not able to read the "versionLabel" span.
Can someeone suggest some way here ?

Comment: If you are using Selenium, you can simply locate any element by `find_element`. This works in the same way as you inspect in the devtools. You can try @AbiSaran 's solution.

Comment: And you **can't** scrape dynamic web pages using jsoup.

Answer (score 1):

This will get the version from the 'versionLabel':

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span[@id='versionLabel'])[2]").text
```